# Make constraints to fit cylinder into centre of icosahedra joint

Tags: modeling, constraints

This is a little cylinder I want to fit into the exact centre of joint of icosahedra. How to make proper constrains?

[image]

1. Distance from cylinder to each bend must be equal
2. Central axis of cylinder should be normal to circumscribed sphere.

[untitled.blend](https://www.sendspace.com/file/1tnw6b)

[geodesic dome online](https://dompodrobno.ru/raschet_kupolnoi_kryschi/#7/12_Piped_D80_3V_R2.25_beams_40x40)

Answer (score 3):

You can get there in three steps:

1. Select inner faces of the joint
2. Co *Mesh > Snap > Cursor to selected* (3D cursor is the center for new objects)
3. Add a cylinder with six sides - it will be precisely in the middle

[image]

Comment: Thank you for response, make case is slightly harder. Bends are not in the same flatness. They form a sphere dome. With you instruction i can make only one part of what i want.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe taking a step back.. if so, apologies..

1. Enable the shipped Add-on 'Add Mesh: Geodesic Domes', create desired dome.
2. On a copy of the dome, <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete Only Faces* (The instancer can be set not to render, anyway)
3. In its Instancing panel, set to *Verts*, and A*lign to Vertex Normal*
4. Parent your cylinder to the dome. The cylinder's mesh  will need to be aligned along its local Y axis in Edit Mode.

[image]

5. On the other copy, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel the vertices
6. Again, delete faces.. select one of the new short edges and  <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> *Select Similar* > *Length*
7. Delete those, and *Object > Convert* the remainder to a curve.
8. Set the curve's U resolution to 1, and use its native *Bevel*, also at the lowest resolution, to give a square profile to the spars.

[image]

9. Convert back to a mesh if desired, and combine the copies.

[image]

... something along these lines? Tweak, take the bits which serve your purposes?

Comment: Phew dodged a bullet almost posting same (well dupliverts part) but so much lesser (you are a master illustrator) answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181117/set-items-axis-to-pass-through-world-origin#comment303018_181117  Worth mentioning the instances are aligned local Y axis to vert normal?

Comment: @batFINGER :) Done. This _is_ counter-intuitive, at least, to me. I really would have expected it to be Z? There's usually a consistent grammar to these things in Blender.. I must just not have twigged, yet.