# Set item's axis to pass through world origin

Tags: modeling, transforms

[image]

I want to rotate cylinder to make its central axis pass through cursor/origin. How?

[related Q](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181085)

Comment: Script wise https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19533/align-object-to-vector-using-python  Can add an empty at origin and track the cylinders z axis to it via a track to constraint.  Move or dupe and will maintain tracking  to empty.

Comment: Could also be done in one fell swoop with dupliverts from the geodesics verts manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/verts.html#verts  example https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/157837/15543